# Swagger + Slimframework error on route

Tags: php, api, routes, swagger, slim

i'm creating an Api with Slimphp. I've generated the doc and Client+Server files with Swagger.io. Now i'm trying to use some routes and it is giving me an error

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to App\v1\Api\ContactApi::__construct() must be an instance of App\v1\lib\ApiClient, instance of Slim\Container given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\DigitalMade\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php on line 64 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\DigitalMade\app\v1\Api\ContactApi.php on line 55

The route used:

> $this->GET('', App\v1\Api\ContactApi::class.':getContactAsList');

Link to Classes
 - ApiClient: https://gist.github.com/miorac/d2232ca71a3feaa0500f9f992d0a7e87
 - ContactApi: https://gist.github.com/miorac/c9373136ed2b694f59a2fbb0dfea3ebe

Does someone knows what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a factory with the Container which implements the `ContactApi`

Something like this:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container[App\v1\Api\ContactApi::class] = function ($c) {
    $apiClient = new App\v1\lib\ApiClient();
    return new App\v1\Api\ContactApi($apiClient);
}
```

Slim will then use this factory to instantiate the `ContactApi` object before routing.

Comment: DUDE, I LOVE YOU <3